How to clear the polylines when the itinerary change?
I'm loading a page with a map and routes already loaded.
We can change the origin, destination and transportation mode with this form :
<div id="formulaire" class="box">

    <input id="start" type="text" value="$4DTEXT($vo_personne.origine)" class="input my-1">
    <input id="end" type="text" value="$4DTEXT($vo_personne.destination)" class="input my-1">
    
    <div class="select my-1">
    <select id="mode_transport">
        <option value="DRIVING">Voiture</option>
        <option value="TRANSIT">Transports</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Actualiser le trajet" class="button my-1">
    
</div>

When I'm changing something in the form, the map change, the routes too but I didn't find a way to clear the old routes (polylines) on the previous map.
This is my JS code
<script>

// onglets jquery UI
$( function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
} );

// Google Maps
function initMap() {
    directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        polylineOptions : { // works only on the active path
            strokeColor: '#0047b3',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 7
        }
    });
    
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("carte"), {
        zoom: 5,  
        center: { lat : 46.603354, lng: 1.888334}, // france
    });

    directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
    
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer);

    document.getElementById("mode_transport").addEventListener("change", () => {
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer);
    }); 
    document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("change", () => {
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer);
    }); 
    document.getElementById("end").addEventListener("change", () => {
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer);
    });
    
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer) {
    
    start = document.getElementById("start").value;
    end = document.getElementById("end").value; 
    selectedMode = document.getElementById("mode_transport").value;
    
    directionsRenderer.setMap(map); 
    
    directionsRenderer.setPanel(document.getElementById("itineraire"));

    directionsRequest = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode],
        provideRouteAlternatives: true,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
    };

    directionsService
        .route(directionsRequest)
        .then((response) => {
            directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
            
        //  console.log (response);
        //  console.log (response.routes.length + ' routes');
        //  status = (response.status);

            if (status === 'OK') {
                // les routes trouvées
                for (var i = 0, len = response.routes.length; i < len; i++) {
                    new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                        map: map,
                        directions: response,
                        routeIndex: i
                    });
                    
                    // route sélectionnée par défaut ?
                    // lui attribuer un ID ?
                    var polyline = response.routes[i] ;
                }   
                    
                console.log (polyline);
            }

        })
        .catch((e) => window.alert("Directions request failed due to " + e));
}

// création de la carte à l'ouverture de la page
window.initMap = initMap;

</script>

I'm a beginner and it's my first map, so I didn't find a solution to update the polylines.
The new ones are good but the oldest ones should be deleted or hidden.
I've tried to change the events listenners by adding polyline.remove() but it create this error :
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: polyLinePath is not defined
document.getElementById("mode_transport").addEventListener("change", () => {
        polyline.remove();
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer);
    }); 
    document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("change", () => {
        polyline.remove();
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer);
    }); 
    document.getElementById("end").addEventListener("change", () => {
        polyline.remove();
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer);
    });


Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (preferably a working StackSnippet in the question itself)

polyline is local to the directionsService callback function.

If I create a map with the posted code, it displays a route, if I change the route, the route changes, the polyline is not left behind.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

fiddle

Thanks for the example. I create one why my code, if you change something (origin, destination or mode), all polylines will stay on the map.
https://jsfiddle.net/melodynelson/rbju9413/14/

You need to keep references to the directionsRenderer objects you are using to display the routes.
In the global scope:
let renderer = [];

Then when you create the renderers, push them onto that array:
for (var i = 0, len = response.routes.length; i < len; i++) {
  renderer.push(new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: map,
    directions: response,
    routeIndex: i
  }));
}   

Then to remove the routes from the map, set the map to null on those renderers:
function removeOldRoutes() {
  for (var i=0; i < renderer.length; i++) {
    renderer[i].setMap(null);
  }
  renderer = [];
}

proof of concept fiddle
code snippet


let map;
let renderer = [];
// Google Maps
function initMap() {
    directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        polylineOptions : { // works only on the active path
            strokeColor: '#0047b3',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 7
        }
    });
    
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("carte"), {
        zoom: 5,  
        center: { lat : 46.603354, lng: 1.888334}, // france
    });

    directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
    
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer);

    document.getElementById("mode_transport").addEventListener("change", () => {
        removeOldRoutes()
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer);
    }); 
    document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("change", () => {
        removeOldRoutes()
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer);
    }); 
    document.getElementById("end").addEventListener("change", () => {
        removeOldRoutes()
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer);
    });
    
}
function removeOldRoutes() {
  for (var i=0; i < renderer.length; i++) {
    renderer[i].setMap(null);
  }
  renderer = [];
}
function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer) {
    
    start = document.getElementById("start").value;
    end = document.getElementById("end").value; 
    selectedMode = document.getElementById("mode_transport").value;
    
    directionsRenderer.setMap(map); 
    
    directionsRenderer.setPanel(document.getElementById("itineraire"));

    directionsRequest = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode],
        provideRouteAlternatives: true,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
    };

    directionsService
        .route(directionsRequest)
        .then((response) => {
            directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
            
            console.log (response);
            console.log (response.routes.length + ' routes');
            status = (response.status);

            if (status === 'OK') {
                // les routes trouvées
                for (var i = 0, len = response.routes.length; i < len; i++) {
                    console.log("rendering route "+i);
                    renderer.push(new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                        map: map,
                        directions: response,
                        routeIndex: i
                    }));
                }   
            }

        })
        .catch((e) => window.alert("Directions request failed due to " + e));
}

// création de la carte à l'ouverture de la page
window.initMap = initMap;
/* 
 * Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element
 * that contains the map. 
 */
#carte {
  height: 80%;
}

/* 
 * Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. 
 */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>StackSnippet</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="carte"></div>
<div id="formulaire" class="box">

    <input id="start" type="text" value="Paris" class="input my-1">
    <input id="end" type="text" value="Marseille" class="input my-1">
    
    <div class="select my-1">
    <select id="mode_transport">
        <option value="DRIVING">Voiture</option>
        <option value="TRANSIT">Transports</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Actualiser le trajet" class="button my-1">
    
</div>
    <!-- 
      The `defer` attribute causes the script to execute after the full HTML
      document has been parsed. For non-blocking uses, avoiding race conditions,
      and consistent behavior across browsers, consider loading using Promises. See
      https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/load-maps-js-api
      for more information.
      -->
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>



